# .htaccess redirect example.com/magento/index.php to example.com/?

Tags: .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

I have Magento installed in a subdirectory, the path to Magento is `example.com/magento`.

I have an `.htaccess` file in the root, 'example.com' as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^magento/(.+)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$         /magento/$1    [QSA,L]
```

In the standard Magento `.htaccess` in `example.com/magento` I have uncommented the RewriteBase directive as follows:

```
RewriteBase /magento/
```

But when I type `example.com` the browser shows `example.com/magento`

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: It should be `RewriteBase /` I think, as this .htaccess is in your site's root. Other than that your first condition/rule might not match and therefore not redirect the user.

Comment: @Sumurai8, maybe you are right. but I'm a dummy about .htaccess config. I'll be glad if you could help me about this question.

Answer (score 0):

Leave RewriteBase commented

```
# RewriteBase /magento/
```

Try this, instead, in your /.htacccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /magento/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

and add this to your magento/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . / [L]
</IfModule>
```